# How to clear the screen when using shell mode in emacs?

Tags: command-line, emacs

I cannot using the command "clear" to clear the screen in emacs shell mode as I can in the linux terminal.
So how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell mode is not a terminal emulator, the way that M-x term is, so "clear" does not have meaning there.

Comment: What's the difference between term and shell in emacs?

Comment: term is a full blown terminal emulator think of it as xterm running in emacs where as shell is just a basic pipe to bash.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but as of today, `comint-clear-buffer` (`C-c M-o`) clears the buffer.

This function should also work for all comint-based buffers (Shell-mode, SQLi-mode, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Read my comment to John Wiegley, unless you use term clear won't work you can however just to C-x-h which will select all text in buffer and hit delete.

Comment: I use `M-x erase-buffer` to clean up a huge shell buffer.

Comment: it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

you can use C-L, it actually does not clear the screen, but moves the whole screen to up, and that make it look like you really cleared the screen

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Hadoop 2.5 and HBase 0.95. You can use system("clear") on hbase shell